# Edge vertical scroll bar flicks of and on as I type

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge's vertical scroll bar is flickering off and on as I type in text boxes. This causes the items on the screen to move left and right by the width of the scroll bar  as I type. This does not happen in Firefox.

When the screen first loads there is a vertical scroll bar. When I put in the first keystroke it disappears, when I put the next keystroke in it comes back.  It does not matter what field I am typing in and it does not matter if I change fields. Odd numbered key strokes cause the scroll bar to disappear, even numbered key strokes bring it back.

Anyone else seeing this?

- Edge Version 80.0.361.33 (Official build) beta (64-bit)
- Core 3.1
- Visual Studio 2019  16.4

Comment: It would be easier if you could share any demo of your problem here.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). without any code, it is hard to narrow down the problem.

Comment: A way to reproduce this would be very beneficial for anyone who would like to help. A shot in the dark guess would be there's something explicit manipulating something in the DOM's box model structure that's toggling overflow but we can't fix what we can't troubleshoot. Luckily there's [light at the end of the tunnel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4501095/download-the-new-microsoft-edge-based-on-chromium) either way. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Let me think on that.  It really is rather huge but I understand.

Comment: I missed a step building the view.   It's all part of an admin framework I bought so I really can not post it.  Thanks everyone